# How to check if current OS is Windows 7?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, version

I'm developing a windows app (it depends on DirectShow, so no Linux, etc).

It will run, for now, in XP and Windows 7 (no Vista support).

However, there's a piece of code that behaves very differently in XP or Windows 7, so I need to know in which system I am, to make a workaround. As I don't support Vista -and even if I did, I guess there wouldn't be much differences- I don't care if Vista and 7 are identified as the same OS, although I'd prefer they weren't.

Just in case, I'm developing in c++, and I don't want to maintain two different executables, and I'd prefer a language-agnostic way to do it.

So, my question: What's The Right Way(tm) to check at run-time which windows version is running?

Comment: You're supporting XP and 7 while skipping Vista? I'd love to hear the reasoning behing that...

Comment: @Greg: Because Vista was one of things we would very much like to forget, much like Windows ME, Windows 1.0 and MSDOS 4 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - I've never really understood people's problems with Vista. I'm using it on my laptop right now because it doesn't seem worth the effort to reinstall with 7. Ok the out-of-the-box version had a few usability gripes but running SP2 it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Greg: We sell servers with our software (and of course, OS) already installed. We have some already installed on XP but it's becoming really hard to get XP licenses nowadays, so we are beginning to install 7. In short: We don't support Vista because we don't need to. Not my decision, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28VS.85%29.aspx) referenced by Naveen has an important remark, that might be relevant for your scenario, too:

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present. This is because the operating system may have had new features added in a redistributable DLL. Rather than using `GetVersionEx` to determine the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence of the feature itself.

Checking for a particular feature can be done using the [`IsOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773795%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

[`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to retrieve the OS version. However, be aware that the OS will identify differently depending on whether compatibility mode is in effect or not.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not supporting any new feature, it's just that some DirectShow filters seem to behave differently in XP and 7 when applying some ugly low-level hacks (while some others behave differently even in normal conditions). For now, knowing the OS version seems enough.